# Different border images on top, right, left, bottom

Tags: html, css, forms, border

Good day. I have an image and this image should be as border, but it must rotate. Border-top-image etc. doesn't work. Help me please. How I can rotate image in borders or how I can provide different images for different sides?

Border image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaehY.jpg

Comment: you want all side different images? or same image to be applied only at borders

Comment: I think he wants the same image, in rotated form, on each side.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I guess:
Rotate the image in a photo edit program such a Photoshop. make one for every border.

or you can rotate your image with the following CSS:

```
.leftBorder . rightBorder {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);     /* Chrome and other webkit browsers */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);        /* FF */
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);          /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);         /* IE9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);             /* W3C complaint browsers */
}
```

this will turn them 180 degrees, you can change the amount however you like. 
You will have to have a Main div and place you left,right and top,bottom images inside the desired div.

hope this helps you out.

Comment: how to make for every border? for inputs

Comment: try messing around with the code a bit. You have one div, and then put all the images in, for left make a class called left, for right make a class right, top, bottom. The top and bottom only need to be placed, because the image is already vertical.. for left and right you need a 90deg angle. But this solution will cause trouble in the future since I'm guessing you not that experienced. It would be better and easier to just make a square image in photoshop with the borders you want and then use that as a background for the div.